# how can Python handle images in Console program?

Tags: python, image, class, inheritance, jpeg

## My problem is Read the Requirements #5 I dont know how to handle images in a Console Program..

## Develop a program following the requirements below.

Reminders:

- All attributes, function names, and parameters in the instructions are in double quotes, but when you put them in your program, it should be without the double quotes.
- When talking about constructor parameters, the "self" is understood to be a constant, i.e. if it was instructed to have a constructor without parameters, it is understood that the only parameter will be "self"

```py
class Item:
    pass


class Gadget(Item):
    pass


class MusicalInstrument(Item):
    pass


class Appliance(Item):
    pass


class Furniture(Item):
    pass


class Plant(Item):
    pass
```

## Requirement #1:

-Given the above class definitions, modify the class Item to have a constructor accepting a parameter and setting an attribute, "name".

- The class Item should have a function named, "print_name". When called, it will print to screen the following (without the double quotes):
- "The name of this item is [name]"
- where [name] is the attribute name of the instance
- e.g. "The name of this item is Trombone"

## Requirement #2:

- Add a constructor to the Gadget class, accepting parameters "name" and "version". The class should set the object's attribute "version". It should call the parent constructor and pass the "name" parameter.
- Add a constructor to the MusicalInstrument class, accepting parameters "name" and "instrument_type".  The class should set the object's attribute "instrument_type". It should call the parent constructor and pass the "name" parameter.
- Add a constructor to the Appliance class, accepting parameters "name" and "wattage".  The class should set the object's attribute "wattage". It should call the parent constructor and pass the "name" parameter.
- Add a constructor to the Furniture class, accepting parameters "name" and "color".  The class should set the object's attribute "color". It should call the parent constructor and pass the "name" parameter.
- Add a constructor to the Plant class, accepting parameters "name" and "number_of_leaves".  The class should set the object's attribute "number_of_leaves". It should call the parent constructor and pass the "name" parameter.

## Definition of terms:

- Gadget's version attribute may refer to its Firmware or OS version.
- Musical Instrument's instrument_type can be one of the following: percussion, woodwind, string, brass, or keyboard.
- Appliance's wattage is the operating power (in terms of watts) of the appliance
- Furniture's color refers to the dominant color of the specific furniture
- Plant's number_of_leaves is the literally how many leaves the plant has

## Requirement #3:

- For each class, with the exception of the Item class, add a function named, "print_other_attribute", which when called, it will print to screen the following (without the double quotes):
- "Another attribute of this item is its [the attribute aside from the name]: [the value of the attribute]"
- e.g. for musical instrument, "Another attribute of this item is instrument_type: brass"

## Requirement #3:

- Look inside and around your house, and identify 5 things that would inherit from any of the following parent classes:
- Gadget, MusicalInstrument, Appliance, Furniture, or Plant

## Define each child class with the proper parent.

- The constructor should accepts no parameters, and should call its parent's constructor passing the appropriate parameters based on the actual item

## Requirement #4:

- For the 5 classes you have defined in Requirement #3, instantiate an object and call its print_name and print_other_attribute functions
- If your program is correct, it should print 10 lines to the screen

## Requirement #5:

- Include in the attachment 5 pictures corresponding to each of the item you have selected.
- It should be in Jpeg format (*.jpg / *.jpeg)

Comment: There isn't a way to have an image in the console. I interpret Requirement #5 to be separate from your code, send in pictures of what you are using as objects. I'd follow up with your professor to clarify

Comment: yes I've noticed that, thanks guy